# How to initialize a class member reference to the empty string in the default constructor

Tags: c++, reference, default-constructor

How can I initialize a class member reference to the empty string ("") in this default constructor.

```
class Document {
    string& title;
    string* summary;

    Document() : title(/*what to put here*/), summary(NULL) {}
};
```

Comment: _`/*what to put here*/`_ Nothing? `std::string` is an empty sequence by default.

Comment: How do you have the title string declared in your class?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not if it's really a reference.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well the OP has to proove so first in their post.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There, I was right ;)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's said in question **class member reference**.

Comment: @user230137 People use weird wording all the time. As for your question, it's not reasonably possible, unless you provide another `std::string dummy;` in your class and pass a reference to this one. Anyway you wouldn't be able to change it later on.

Comment: Depends. Why do you use a reference / pointer to `std::string`? BTW: Might `summary` be better off using `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: You need to find an existing string object and initialize the reference from that. If that sounds nonsensical, it should make you question the reason you want to have a reference data member in a default constructable type.

Comment: It's my pur teacher who want us to implement this class this way.

Comment: @user230137: I seriously hope he wants you to do this just to show you the technical details of reference members, not any supposed merits.

Comment: @user230137 _"It's my pur teacher who want us to implement this class this way."_ Did they demand you to provide a default constructor for the implementation?

Comment: He say that we need always program a default constructor by passing default values.

Comment: @user230137: Not all classes need a default constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sensible way to do this. A reference must refer to an existing object (an ever better way to put it would be that a reference **is** the existing object), and the `std::string` that would be constructed in the initialiser list from `""` would be destroyed after the constructor has finished, leaving you with undefined behaviour on every attempt to use your member variable.

Now, I said "no sensible way". There are hacks to achieve what you want, of course, e.g.:

```
// bad hack:
std::string &EmptyStringThatLivesForever()
{
    static std::string string;
    return string;
}

class Document {
    string& title;
    string* summary;

    Document() : title(EmptyStringThatLivesForever()), summary(NULL) {}
};
```

But I doubt that such a trick would survive any serious code review.

The real solution is to get rid of the reference:

```
class Document {
    string title;
    string* summary;

    Document() : title(""), summary(NULL) {}
};
```

Comment: Since `title` is a `string&` and not a `const string&`, it's evidently a bad idea that more than one instance of `Document` share the same one.

Comment: @rici: Well, I called it a "bad hack" :) Anyway, since it's a reference, it immediately communicates the idea that it may be shared between this object and other parts of the application. And without knowing the real motivation of the member being a reference, the only useful general advice is to turn it into a normal member variable.